# Retrieving a session without the use of cookies or cache

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to create an application without the use of cookies or cache. I.e when cookies or cache is cleared I am still able to lookup the session on the server.
Is there anything in the request headers I can utilise? I could use the IPAddress as a key but this changes from location to location. I need a key I can use per device.

Comment: Thought about localstorage ?

Comment: Keep in mind that browsers allow users to manage their cookies, `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` to help protect privacy. If a user deletes this data, it could be because they do not want to be tracked or identified by sites they've previously visited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FingerPrintJs2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2), it doesn't rely on cookies or cache and has an extremely high accuracy (something like 94% I believe).

This is an evolution of the original [FingerPrintJs](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs), which has a much more in depth explanation of how it works.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess I could use - `Language,Color Depth,Screen Resolution, Timezone, CPU class, Platform` to create a fingerprint that is the same across different browsers

Comment: yea, and it would maintain the same unique "user" for that device